# Ruby on Rails: Push Posts in to a hash and then show them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a twitter-copy and right now I'm trying to get all the posts from all the users you follow and then show them on the home page. I've done this in PHP before, but I'm new at RoR so I might be trying to do this the wrong way.

a User has many Subscriptions
and a Subscription belongs to User

a User has many Posts
and a Post belongs to User

This is what i've got so far:

**session_controller.rb**

```
def get_posts
  @sub = @current_user.subscriptions.first
  Post.where("user_id = ?", @sub.following_id).find_each do |tweet|
    render partial: 'shared/tweet', locals: {tweet: tweet}
  end
end
```

I know .first gets only the first subscription, but I wanted to try to get just something out.

**home.html.erb**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Tweet</th>
    </tr>
    <%= yield %>
</table>
```

**_tweet.html.erb**

```
<div class="tweet">
    <td>Username here somehow</td>
    <td><%= tweet.content %></td>
</div>
```

But right now nothing is coming up in the table.. So, what am I doing wrong? (am I doing anything right at all?)

Comment: Why are you inserting a td inside a div?

Comment: oh.. forgot to change that.. Didn't use a table from the beginning.

Comment: Where are you using `get_posts` helper method?

Comment: sry.. the get_posts is in the session_controller.. changed this back and forth so much I'm all confused now..

Comment: I think there are some problems with naming conventions and routes. If you want I'm available to chat.

Comment: Yes, please! Need all the help I can get.

Comment: When there are too much comments here it suggest to use a chat... meanwhile, are you sure you are going to `get_posts` action?

Comment: nope... forgot to run it. added `get_posts` to `def home` and now I get an error that says i cant render or redirect more than once per action @cortex

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29375/discussion-between-cortex-and-alexander)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**session_controller.rb**

```
def get_posts
  @sub = @current_user.subscriptions.first
  @tweets = Post.where("user_id = ?", @sub.following_id)
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Tweet</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
     <%= render 'shared/tweet', tweet: tweet %>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**_tweet.html.erb**

```
<tr class="tweet">
    <td><%= tweet.user.name %></td> # Not sure
    <td><%= tweet.content %></td>
</tr>
```

EDIT:

To get all the tweets for all the subscritions:

```
following_ids = @current_user.subscriptions.map(&:following_id)
@tweets = Post.where(user_id: following_ids)
```